# Laravel belongsToMany not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, models

I have the following schema set up:

users:

- id

departments:

- id

department_user:

- id
- department_id
- user_id

I also have the following relationships set up:

**User Model**

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Resources\Eloquent\Models\Department', 'department_users');
}
```

**Department Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'department_users');
}
```

For some reason, when I am trying to access through the user model `$user->departments`, it doesn't work - but `$department->users` does.

Outputting the eloquent query is as follows:

```
select `departments`.*, `department_users`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `department_users`.`department_id` as `pivot_department_id` from `departments` inner join `department_users` on `departments`.`id` = `department_users`.`department_id` where `department_users`.`user_id` is null
```

I can't seem to figure out why it is looking to see if `department_users.user_id` is null, when it should be looking for the user's id.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you coming up with the `$user` variable?  Is the user hasn't been saved yet, the id would be null I believe.

Comment: Why you define return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'department_users'); - remove second arg 'department_users' and in User model also remove second arg. Its optional table name and I see misspeling "department_users" in this definition vs your schema at top "department_user" - missing last "s"

Comment: The `$user` variable is already assigned to a model which has been pulled from the database. I.E: `$user = User::find(1)`

Comment: said foreign and primary key in the relationship functions. May be these will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, if I make the relationship the following - it works.

```
 return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'department_users')->orWhere('department_users.user_id', $this->id);
```

If anyone knows why, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set up your models like it is suggested in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships):

So your models would look something like this:

**User Model**

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('path\to\your\model\Department');
}
```

**Department Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(path\to\your\model\User);
}
```

Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order.So you don't need extra arguments when defining your relationship and Laravel also by default, makes model keys present on the pivot object. And then you can do something like this:

```
$department = path\to\your\model\Department::find(1);

foreach ($department->users as $user) {
    echo $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my raw query was working, but in the Laravel code base - does not

I had named my many-to-many table project_technology, and in relation I had

"public function technologies"

```
public function technologies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Technology::class,'project_technology');
}
```

after re-reading the documentation, I've changed my relation to

"technology" and worked properly

```
public function technology(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Technology::class,'project_technology');
}
```

In addition:
and yes I know that many to many tables should be plural, but thought that will not be needed and I will write it on my own, so ... after spending some time I've figured it out

my migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_technology', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->uuid('project_id');
        $table->uuid('technology_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('project_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('projects')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('technology_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('technologies')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34677311)